# How to start a new goroutine each time a channel is updated

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I am making a program that monitors different webpages, each time a new url is added to a page, I would like to start a new goroutine to scrape the new url.
I am trying to simulate this like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var Wg sync.WaitGroup
    link := make(chan string)
    startList := []string{}
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
            //should simulate the monitoring of the original web page
            nextLink := fmt.Sprintf("cool-website-%d", i)
            link <- nextLink
        }
    }()

    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        newLink := <-link
        startList = append(startList, newLink)
        Wg.Add(1)
        go simulateScraping(i, startList[i])
        Wg.Done()
    }
    Wg.Wait()
}

func simulateScraping(i int, link string) {
    fmt.Printf("Simulating process %d\n", i)
    fmt.Printf("scraping www.%s.com\n", link)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(30) * time.Second)
    fmt.Printf("Finished process %d\n", i)
}
```

This results in the following error `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`.
How do I only start the simulateScraping function each time that newLink is updated or when startList is appended to?

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot see how the code you provided could lead to a deadlock (tested it on a [few machines](https://go.dev/play/p/BB_ME_0UWJg) to be sure!). It will not do what you expect due to the issue with `wg.Done` (as per the answer from @Alex) but should not deadlock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see several problems with the code.

1. Wait group is useless in the code because `Wg.Done` is called immediately and does not wait until the `simulateScraping` finishes, because it's running in parallel.

To fix this, the closure function could be used

```golang
        go func(i int) {
            simulateScraping(i, newLink)
            Wg.Done()
        }(i)
```

2. Instead of an increment loop, I would use for-each range loop. It allows code to be executed as soon as a new value get to a channel and automatically breaks when the channel closes.

```golang
    var i int
    for newLink := range link {
        Wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            simulateScraping(i, newLink)
            Wg.Done()
        }(i)
        i++
    }
    Wg.Wait()
```

3. `startList := []string{}` Looks useless. Not sure how it was supposed to be used.
4. Channel must be closed.

```golang
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
            //should simulate the monitoring of the original web page
            nextLink := fmt.Sprintf("cool-website-%d", i)
            link <- nextLink
        }
       close(link) // Closing the channel
    }()
```

The whole code

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var Wg sync.WaitGroup
    link := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
            //should simulate the monitoring of the original web page
            nextLink := fmt.Sprintf("cool-website-%d", i)
            link <- nextLink
        }
        close(link)
    }()

    var i int
    for newLink := range link {
        Wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            simulateScraping(i, newLink)
            Wg.Done()
        }(i)
        i++
    }
    Wg.Wait()
}

func simulateScraping(i int, link string) {
    fmt.Printf("Simulating process %d\n", i)
    fmt.Printf("scraping www.%s.com\n", link)
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    fmt.Printf("Finished process %d\n", i)
}
```

Here is a good talk about "[Concurrency Patterns In Go](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEKjSzIwAdA)"